# CirclePageIndicator in fragment

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am currently working on an android app. When I initialised an UI element and set the content of the UI element inside OnPageScrolled in the fragment, it doesn't work only in fragment, but it works in activity class. Here is the code:

```
circleIndicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener(){

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    switch(arg0){
                    case 0:{

                        WorkoutDetailsFragment.this.txtNote = (EditText) getSherlockActivity().findViewById(R.id.editTextNote);
                        WorkoutDetailsFragment.this.txtNote.setText("hello");
                        WorkoutDetailsFragment.this.lstViewList1 = (ListView) getSherlockActivity().findViewById(R.id.lstViewlist1);
                        WorkoutDetailsFragment.this.lstViewList2 = (ListView) getSherlockActivity().findViewById(R.id.lstViewlist2);
                        p2 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
                        arrayList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
                        arrayList2.add(getString(R.string.Recovery_rate));
                        arrayList2.add("");
                        p2.add(arrayList2);

                        adapter1 = new ListViewAdapterwithoutArrowHorizontal(getSherlockActivity(),
                                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, p2);

                        p2 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
                        arrayList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
                        arrayList2.add(getString(R.string.Diet_Points));
                        arrayList2.add("");
                        p2.add(arrayList2);

                        adapter2 = new ListViewAdapterwithoutArrowHorizontal(getSherlockActivity(),
                                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, p2);
                        WorkoutDetailsFragment.this.lstViewList1.setAdapter(adapter1);

                        WorkoutDetailsFragment.this.lstViewList2.setAdapter(adapter2);
                        //LoadWorkoutResult();
                        //LoadWorkoutDetails();
                        if (adapter2.getItem(1).get(0).equals(getString(R.string.Diet_Points))
                                && extras != null) {
                            adapter2.getItem(1).remove(1);
                            adapter2.getItem(1).add(
                                    extras.getInt(getString(R.string.dietpoints)) + "");
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "testing..........", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    }
                    case 1:{
                        //mapview = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
                        //  break;
                    }
                    case 2:{

                        //multitouchplot = (MultitouchPlot) findViewById(R.id.multitouchPlot);
                        //series = new SimpleXYSeries();
                        //splitchart = new SplitChart(series, multitouchplot, isMile);
                        //LoadSplitChart();
                        //break;
                    }

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            });
```

Can anyone know where the issue is? Do I need to use the circleppageindicator adapter extending FragmentPageAdapter?

Thanks for any helps in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize your circle indicator as you like ,it's up to your need, the way you want it

[**Here is My Implementation**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433281/android-fragment-pager-and-custom-page-indicator-viewpagerindicator-created-by)

It works perfectly for me

**Note** : You can also find the library i used to create [**page indicator**](http://viewpagerindicator.com/)